# How to assign Invoice RefNbr before saving the invoice

Tags: acumatica

I have set my invoice to Manual Numbering
[image]

And I want to assign the invoice number(RefNbr) - if blank, before saving the invoice (AR301000). I've overridden the RowPersisting event as follow:

```
public class ARInvoiceEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
{

    protected void ARInvoice_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e, PXRowPersisting InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
      var row = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
      if (row != null)
      {
        //BB-<timestamp> as inv# for testing only
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.RefNbr))
          row.RefNbr = "BB-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmsstt");
      }
      if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
         InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
    }

}
```

If I raised a new invoice w/out any lines and saved it. It correctly assigned the Reference Nbr as expected.

[image]

Problem is if I raised a new invoice WITH lines. Its complaining that the RefNbr is blank.

[image]

What am I missing ? How do I fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: Please add the stack trace of Acumatica ERP and specify the exact line where you are getting this exception

Comment: seems like the lines going in are too late to receive your updated value in the batch header. Do the tran lines row persisting fire BEFORE your ARInvoice row persisting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acumatica's **PXDBDefaultAttribute** only updates field of the dependent records when both the source field of the parent record and the foreign key field of the dependent record are not empty.

When a dependent record is inserted into the cache, **PXDBDefaultAttribute** will copy the source field value from the parent record to the field it decorates from the dependent record. While the framework is saving new parent record into the database, it first raises **RowPersisting** event for the parent record. **PXDBDefaultAttribute** subscribes to the **RowPersisting** event of the parent record type to save the original source field value:

- to locate the parent record after it was saved to the database
- or to use it as a restore point for the dependent field in case of an aborted transaction

Also, **PXDBDefaultAttribute** subscribes to the **RowPersisting** event of the dependent record type to update the foreign key field with the actual source field value, that has just been recorded in the database. To update the foreign key field **PXDBDefaultAttribute** must first locate the parent record using the original source field value obtained earlier in the **RowPersisting** event handler of the parent record type. In case the foreign key field value appears to be empty, there is no chance for **PXDBDefaultAttribute** to locate the parent record for it and it simply leaves the dependent field empty. This is what eventually is causing the error "***RefNbr cannot be empty***".

With all that being said, I believe it won't be possible to achieve the desired results if leaving AR Invoice Reference Number empty until it gets saved to the database. As an alternative, let me suggest to default AR Invoice Reference Number to some constant, like ***< ENTER >***, and at the same time replace it with the actual number within the **ARInvoice_RowPersisting** handler:

```
using PX.Data;
using System;

namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
    public class ARInvoiceNumberingCstAttribute : ARInvoiceType.NumberingAttribute
    {
        public const string EnterRefNbr = "<ENTER>";

        protected override string GetNewNumber()
        {
            string newNumber = base.GetNewNumber();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newNumber))
            {
                newNumber = EnterRefNbr;
            }
            return newNumber;
        }

        public override void RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (GetNewNumber() == EnterRefNbr) return;

            base.RowPersisting(sender, e);
        }
    }

    public class ARInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
    {
        [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(ARInvoiceType.NumberingAttribute))]
        [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
        [ARInvoiceNumberingCst]
        protected void ARInvoice_RefNbr_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
        { }

        protected void ARInvoice_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e, 
            PXRowPersisting InvokeBaseHandler)
        {
            if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
                InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);

            var row = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
            if (row != null)
            {
                //BB-<timestamp> as inv# for testing only
                if (row.RefNbr == ARInvoiceNumberingCstAttribute.EnterRefNbr)
                    row.RefNbr = "BB-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmsstt");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RuslanDev ! Works like a charm. I used the same logic in invoicing in SO screen.

Comment: You're very welcome, @Rick! Good to know your goal has been successfully achieved on 2 different screens.